# Force Oracle use partition pruning

Tags: sql, oracle, partitioning

I use Oracle 11G.

I have next query:

```
select *
  from ARCH_KART H
  join A_NABOR2 N
   on H.LSK = N.LSK
   and :B1 between N.MGFROM AND N.MGTO
  where h.mg = :mg and h.lsk between :C1 and :C2
```

It's a plan:

[image]
How to force Oracle to use a partition pruning on table A_NABOR2?

A_NABOR2 is hash-partitioned table by the "lsk" column, it contains about
100 million records.

Why does Oracle use PARTITION HASH ALL method?

**Upd1**
I added local index: 
create index A_NABOR2_I on A_NABOR2 (MGFROM, MGTO)
  local;

but id didn't help:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                            | Name            | Rows  | Bytes |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT                     |                 |    79 | 28203 |
|   1 |  NESTED LOOPS                        |                 |       |       |
|   2 |   NESTED LOOPS                       |                 |    79 | 28203 |
|   3 |    PARTITION HASH ALL                |                 |    79 |  4345 |
|   4 |     TABLE ACCESS BY LOCAL INDEX ROWID| A_NABOR2        |    79 |  4345 |
|   5 |      INDEX RANGE SCAN                | A_NABOR2_I      |  1024 |       |
|   6 |    PARTITION RANGE SINGLE            |                 |     1 |       |
|   7 |     INDEX RANGE SCAN                 | ARCH_KART_I_LSK |     1 |       |
|   8 |   TABLE ACCESS BY LOCAL INDEX ROWID  | ARCH_KART       |     1 |   302 |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Can you add the index DDL?  Is A_NABOR2 a global index or a local index?  (Thanks for including the explain plan but it might be more helpful to add a text version of it, by using `explain plan for select ...` and then `select * from table(dbms_xplan.display);`.)

Comment: You say that the table has 100million rows.  You need to confirm if the number of rows expected from the Index Range Scan (1024) and Table Access (only 79 ?) is valid.  That expected cardinality of rows indicates very little effort. Also, past the Partition Start and Partition Stop columns in the explain plan -- how many partitions does it expect to go through ?